# id_token not returned in JWT Bearer Token OAuth Flow

Tags: community, oauth2, oauth, jwt, open-id-connect

As per the JWT Bearer token [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0) The id_token will be return if there is a pre-existing approval for the openid.

I have existing approvals for openid for the user. Am I missing something in flow.

How can I retrieve or generate an openid using APEX class.

```
function getToken() {
    var cert = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf-8'),
    };
    claims = {
        "iss": client_key, 
        "sub": username, 
        "aud": salesforceCommunityUrl,
        "exp": new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60
    };
    generated_token = jwt.sign(claims, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
    const formData = {
        grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
        assertion: generated_token,
    };

    var url = salesforceCommunityUrl + tokenUri;
    request.post({url, form: formData}, (err, resp, body) => {
        // There is no id_token that is returned as per the documentation
        res.send(JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us what you've done so far (the code that's being run) and a specific example of the response you get?

Comment: Have you created a connected app? Have you looked at the example code in the  [JWTBearerTokenExchange Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange) docs or the Auth Namespace in general? Please post your code..

Comment: Yes. I have a connected App. I do get the id_token in case of the web-server and user-agent flow but I don't get it in JWT Bearer Flow

Comment: Are you trying to do OIDC Salesforce-to-Salesforce or Salesforce to Third Party Open ID provider?